# String format in form $XX.XX,

Tags: java, string.format

This may be a repeat post, but I cannot find anything exactly to what I am looking for. I'm trying to take a simple double number, in any amount that won't exceed 100, and use string format to format it as XX.XX, such as a value like 45.4000000000

Things I have tried

```
string.format("%f",valuehere)
string.format("%2f",valuehere)
```

I don't quite understand the javadocs, but also I just want to ask as if I add a $ to %f like so $%f, valuehere, it should output it with the dollar sign as well right?

Comment: Not an answer, but as it seems like you're dealing with money, you should know that you shouldn't use `double` or `float` to represent money - use `BigDecimal` instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) for why.

Comment: thanks! i will look into this and try to figure out how to work out where i need the $ i can take it from here

Comment: Use a [currency format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()).  For instance, `String s = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(value);`

Answer (score 2):

You should add the decimal separator to your format. The format should be `%.2f` in your case as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

What does it mean:

`%` is put at the start of the formatting

`.2` Indicates that we want 2 digits after the decimal

`f` indicates that were dealing with a float here

```
String.format("%.2f",500.0545 )
```